# Receive empty Map when sending over Json to server

Tags: node.js, express, http, flutter, server

I'm trying to communicate to a server via rest api (which was created in node.js). When I create the post request, it returns `{}`, and on the server side, it receives `{}` as well, even though I am passing in a json object to the backend.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's the code

**Dart:**
Class:

```
class Post {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;

  Post({this.id, this.title, this.description});

  factory Post.fronJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      description: json['description'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'title': title, 'description': description};
}
```

Post Request

```
 var data = new Post(description: 'my description', title: 'my title').toJson();
  print(data); // {title: my title bro, description: my description}
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.encodeFull('http://localhost:4000'),
    body: data,
  );
  print(response.body); // Returns {}
```

**Server** (node)

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // Returns {}
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the header {"Content-Type":"application/json"} to your http.post request in flutter.

Comment: Perfect! Do you mind explaining why/how that works?

Comment: I am not a very experienced web programmer so please do double check, to my understanding the header "Content-Type" tells the API to check for a specific payload, whether it be an image in bytes or a JSON.